# Rotated rect changes location

Tags: java, android, canvas, rotation

I am trying to rotate a rect and i have to rotate the canvas to do so but the rect changes its location for example, if the rect is in the middle of the screen after the rotation it will go to the side and i cannot figure out how to get it back to the middle.

Here is the code i used:

```
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(45);
    canvas.drawRect(width/2,height/2, width/2+200, height/2+200, paint);
    canvas.restore();
```

Is there a way to rotate the rect without rotating the canvas so its location will stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your rectangle's center differs from the pivot point of the canvas. You can try using [the other rotate method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate(float,%20float,%20float)) to specify the x/y coordinates of the pivot point. As in:

```
int offset = 200;
int left = width/2;
int top = height/2;
int right = left + offset;
int bottom = top + offset;

canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45, left + offset/2, top + offset/2);
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
canvas.restore();
```

---

Edit:

Just tested the code above and verified that it works (given a few tweaks that I just added, above).

Comment: Ok thank you! But I have another problem now, I want to detect a finger touch on the rect but i don't think it will work fine because the canvas won't be angeld as the rect what should I do?

Comment: Sounds like making "the rectangle" its own view (with the parent handling animations, instead), might help because then you can set an [on click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) to handle touch events. Depending on the needs of your app, you may be able to get away with not making a custom view at all and animating a button, instead. You could use default animation APIs or something like [nine old androids](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/) if you need more backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

'canvas.rotate' rotates the canvas around the origin of canvas. Origin is top left corner of canvas at initial state.
If you want to rotate a rectangle around the center of the rectangle, move origin of canvas to the center of the rectancle before using 'canvas.rotate'.

Try following code:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.drawRect(width/2,height/2, width/2+200, height/2+200, paint); // drow rectangle
canvas.translate(width/2+100, height/2+100);  // move origin of canvas to the center of the rectangle
canvas.rotate(45);  // canvas is roteted around the origine that is the center of the rectangle also. As a result, rectangle is roteted around its center.
canvas.translate(-(width/2+100), -(height/2+100));  // restore origin of canvas at original position
canvas.restore();
```